# Whitesource bolt and Azure Devops

Tags: security, azure-devops

I’ve got a project that I run the whitesource bolt plugin on. It all works well, and the report is delivering benefit.

I’ve checked the GitHub plugin and that seems to have a lot more features. Such has fail the build when X level is found

My question

Is there a way to configure the plugin so that it fails the build of a high or medium vulnerability is found using azure devops?